# ngc AoT compiler fails and suggests getting latest node.js and npm

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngc AoT compiler for Angular 2.
This is all built up following along with the Angular Pro book by Adam Freeman.
In his deployment chapter he adds these lines to devDependencies in package.json:

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.0",
"rollup": "0.36.3",
"rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "5.0.5",
"rollup-plugin-uglify": "1.0.1",
"rollup-plugin-alias": "1.2.0",
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "0.4.0"
```

and these lines into scripts in package.json:

```
"ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
"roll": "rollup -c rollup-config.js",
"startbundle": "concurrently \"npm run lite\" \"npm run json\" "
```

Here is the complete package.json file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "html5-history-api": "4.2.7"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.3.2",
    "concurrently": "2.2.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.32",
    "json-server": "0.8.21",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.0",
    "rollup": "0.36.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "5.0.5",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-alias": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "0.4.0"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tscwatch\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run json\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tscwatch": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "json": "json-server data.js -p 3500 -m authMiddleware.js",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "roll": "rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "startbundle": "concurrently \"npm run lite\" \"npm run json\" "
  }
}
```

Here is the tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
  },
  "files": [
    "app/app.module.ts",
    "app/main.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "genDir": "aot",
      "skipMetadataEmit": true
    }
  }
}
```

There is an npm-shrinkWrap.json file but it is too long to include here.

When I run "npm run ngc", I get this error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ngc' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prengc', 'ngc', 'postngc' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prengc: @
6 silly lifecycle @~prengc: no script for prengc, continuing
7 info lifecycle @~ngc: @
8 verbose lifecycle @~ngc: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle @~ngc: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Books\Apress\ProAngular\Chapt10\SportsStore\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\smill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\smill\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle @~ngc: CWD: C:\Books\Apress\ProAngular\Chapt10\SportsStore
11 silly lifecycle @~ngc: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json' ]
12 silly lifecycle @~ngc: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle @~ngc: Failed to exec ngc script
14 verbose stack Error: @ ngc: `ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
15 verbose pkgid @
16 verbose cwd C:\Books\Apress\ProAngular\Chapt10\SportsStore
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ngc"
19 error node v6.11.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error @ ngc: `ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ ngc script 'ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It says make sure I have the latest node and npm.
I installed node just a few weeks ago. 
And I ran npm install -g npm@next
which bumps it up to 5.4.2

This caused all kinds of problems so I rolled everything back to:
node v6.11.3
and
npm 3.10.10 that comes with node version above.

I'm on Windows 10 trying to run Angular 2.

Comment: Any reasons of using old version of angular the latest is 4.4.4, please upgrade to the latest version and also try using yarn to install the dependencies sometimes that is big help

Comment: Well I'm following version two out of the original book and trying to get that to work.  I might have to support 2 somewhere down the line so I figure I should know it.  Then I'll read his updates on version 4.

Comment: BTW - what is yarn.  I would try that.  Can you provide a little guidance?

Comment: yarn is a package manager(similar to npm) but is much faster and reliable. you can install it with "npm install-g yarn" and then rather then npm install, run "yarn" in the project root directory. More info can be found here https://yarnpkg.com/en/